# How to import css from node_modules using webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I've started building my application from the existing kit https://material-ui.com/store/items/devias-kit-pro/. I've changed it to use webpack.config.js which seems to work fine. However, it seems that css files from node_modules don't get imported. For example, index.js file imports css in this way:

```
import 'react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css';
```

but css is not applied. I'm suspecting something is wrong with my webpack configuration which looks like this:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/src');
const PUB_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/public');
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/dist');


module.exports = {
entry: { main: `${SRC_DIR}/index.js` },
output: {
 path: DIST_DIR,
 chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].chunk.js',
 publicPath: '/'

},
resolve: {
 alias: {
   src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
 }
},
module: {
 rules: [
   {
     test: /\.js$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     use: ['babel-loader', 'source-map-loader'],

   },
   {
     test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
     use: {
       loader: 'url-loader',
     },
   },
   {
     test: /\.scss$/,
     use: [
       'style-loader',
       MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
       'css-loader',
       'sass-loader',
     ],
   },
   {
     test: /\.css$/,

     use: [
       { loader: 'style-loader' },
       {
         loader: 'css-loader',
         options: {
           modules: true
         },
       },
       { loader: 'sass-loader' }
     ]
   }
 ],
},
optimization: {
 splitChunks: {
   cacheGroups: {
     css: {
       test: /\.(css|sass|scss)$/,
       name: 'commons',
       chunks: 'all',
       minChunks: 2,
       enforce: true,
     },
   },
 },
},
plugins: [
 new CleanWebpackPlugin({
   cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['dist'],
 }),
 new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
   filename: 'style.[contenthash].css',
 }),
 new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   inject: true,
   title: 'React-Redux-Webpack-Starter-Kit',
   template: `${PUB_DIR}/index.html`,
   filename: 'index.html',
   favicon: `${PUB_DIR}/favicon.ico`,
   meta: {
     viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no',
   },
 }),
 new WebpackMd5Hash(),
 new Dotenv(),
],
devtool: 'source-map',
devServer: {
 port: 3003,
 historyApiFallback: true,
 open: true,

 watchOptions: {
   poll: true,
   ignored: '/node_modules/'
 }
},

};
```

Any suggestion how to solve the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need `sass-loader` for css files?

Comment: I took that configuration from some other post, but I guess not. Removing it doesn't make any difference, though.